# Does there exist a generic "associative array" or "dictionary" typeclass in Haskell for which both Data.Map and Data.HashMap can be made instances?

Tags: haskell, associative-array, typeclass

I would like to design an API that accepts as input a dictionary structure such that all keys are guaranteed unique.  However, I don't want to impose any particular dictionary implementation on the user.

For example, the user should be able to supply either a [`HashMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.9.0/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html#t:HashMap) (from `unordered-containers`) or [`Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#t:Map) (from `containers`) as input.

Is this possible, or even a good idea?

Answer (score 10):

In *lens*, the following classes generalize containers like `HashMap` and `Map`: [`At`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-At.html), [`FunctorWithIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#t:FunctorWithIndex), [`FoldableWithIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#t:FoldableWithIndex), [`TraversableWithIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#t:TraversableWithIndex).

Comment: I was going to mention Kmett's [*keys* package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys) in a separate answer, but then I noticed that its description says "In practice this package is largely subsumed by the *lens* package, but it is maintained for now as it has much simpler dependencies".

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this blog post "[Picnic: put containers into a Backpack](https://kowainik.github.io/posts/2018-08-19-picnic-put-containers-into-a-backpack)" that is an experimental approach to present a unified interface for containers.

The approach using Backpack is summarized by the author as:

> First, you write the types of the desired methods — signatures. And then you implement these signatures for the different data types.

The blog post fills in the details.